# XQuery function to limit the number of records in the output

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery

I have an XQuery file which returns a huge number of data in the output. I just want to show the first 5 records in my output. Here is the xquery code.

```
<html>
<body>
<table border='1'>
<tr><td>Target</td><td>Successor</td><td>Probability</td></tr>

{

let $target := "has"

let $occurrences := doc("KS0.xml")//u//s/w[lower-case(normalize-space()) = $target]

for $successor in distinct-values($occurrences/following-sibling::w[1])

let $frequency := $occurrences/following-sibling::w[1][. = $successor]

let $probability := count($frequency) div count(//u//s/w[lower-case(normalize-space()) = lower-case(normalize-space($successor))])

order by count($frequency) descending

return <tr>
           <td>{$target}</td>
           <td>{$successor}</td>
           <td>{$probability}</td>
       </tr>
}

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query will return a sequence of items, so you can simply use a predicate to limit the number of items returned from the sequence by wrapping your query in parentheticals:

```
(
let $target := "has"
... 
</tr>
)[position() le 5]
```